# Webpages with ActiveX-Controls in Firefox

Tags: firefox, activex

I'm working on an Web application, which contains an ActiveX control (The ActiveX Control is used as drag and drop Target for OLE drag and drop. e.g. Outlook Mails and some other things). Usually the Users of the application are using Internet explorer.

But now I have to support also Firefox, which is a Problem, because Firefox cannot deal with ActiveX Controls.

I identified the following was to display an ActiveX Control in FireFox:

- 'IE Tab' for Firefox (This is no option, because it doesn't work if internet explorer is unistalled)
- ff-activex-host ( seems to be a bit problematic because the documentation says 'web pages need to be written with this plugin in mind.'

Is there any way to display Websites with ActiveX Controls in Firefox, whithout making a special Firefox version of that site?

br
Gerhard

Comment: If you use ActiveX it will not work on different platforms rather than Windows. I do not know exactly what are you developing, but probably you can do the alternative using JavaScript, HTML5 features. Drag drop can be handled using JS. If you are not using specific file formats that can be handled only by ActiveX do not use ActiveX.

Comment: - It is not required that it runs on an OS different than Windows. But it has to run on Firefox on Windows.
- JavaScript and HTML5 is no option, because it doesn't support OLE Drag&Drop as it is required by dropping mails from Outlook
- " do not use ActiveX" that is als no option, because that would require to rewrite the Application
thx for your reply